# I tried to run this program that I found in this website but it does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to run this Python program that I found it in this website but when I run it nothing happens, how can I run this code? Do I need to add anything to the code? I am using this website to run it repl.it: Thank you very much.
................

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

# The following is a database of problems, keywords, and solutions.
PROBLEMS = (('My phone does not turn on.',
             {'power', 'turn', 'on', 'off'},
             ('Smack it with a hammer.',
              'Wrap your phone in duck tape.',
              'Throw it into the ocean.')),
            ('My phone is freezing.',
             {'freeze', 'freezing'},
             ('Dowse it in a petroleum-based product.',
              'Light a match or find a suitable flame source.',
              'Barbecue your phone until it is well done.')),
            ('The screen is cracked.',
             {'cracked', 'crack', 'broke', 'broken', 'screen'},
             ('Find some super glue.',
              'Spread the super glue over the screen of the phone.',
              'Either sit on the phone or place a 100 pounds over it.')),
            ('I dropped my phone in water.',
             {'water', 'drop', 'dropped'},
             ('Blow dry your phone with air below zero degrees Celsius.',
              'Bake it in your oven at three hundred degrees Celsius.',
              'Leave your phone on your roof for one week.')))


# These are possible answers accepted for yes/no style questions.
POSITIVE = tuple(map(str.casefold, ('yes', 'true', '1')))
NEGATIVE = tuple(map(str.casefold, ('no', 'false', '0')))


def main():
    """Find out what problem is being experienced and provide a solution."""
    description = input('Please describe the problem with your phone: ')
    words = {''.join(filter(str.isalpha, word))
             for word in description.lower().split()}
    for problem, keywords, steps in PROBLEMS:
        if words & keywords:
            print('This may be what you are experiencing:')
            print(problem)
            if get_response('Does this match your problem? '):
                print('Please follow these steps to fix your phone:')
                for number, step in enumerate(steps, 1):
                    print('{}. {}'.format(number, step))
                print('After this, your phone should work.')
                print('If it does not, please take it to a professional.')
                break
    else:
        print('Sorry, but I cannot help you.')


def get_response(query):
    """Ask the user yes/no style questions and return the results."""
    while True:
        answer = input(query).casefold()
        if answer:
            if any(option.startswith(answer) for option in POSITIVE):
                return True
            if any(option.startswith(answer) for option in NEGATIVE):
                return False
        print('Please provide a positive or negative answer.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3):

On that site repl.it, before the final `if` I added `print(__name__)` and got output `builtins`. So we see that when running on repl.it, the program fails the very important condition that `__name__ == 'main'`.

You can revise the program to make it work on repl.it just by replacing those final two lines of the program with just this call to function `main`:

```
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running that script on that website you need to call the main function yourself. In the right column please type:

```
main()
```

That you make the main function execute. This was compiled into byte code and on that site you basically started the interpreter and imported the script but you still need need to call the function.

If you are in a computer that has a python interpreter installed you can actually type `python name_of_file.py` and that will run the script by executing the last if statement there.

Answer (score 0):

After you do what Aaron Mansheim says, you will need to provide some input.

Click on 'input' at the upper right of the screen, then key in one of the alternatives mentioned in the script such as,

```
My phone does not turn on.
yes
```

then click on 'Set input'. Then run the code again.

And incidentally, this is perhaps one of the slowest ways I can imagine to learn how to work with Python code. You should install Python on your machine and use it in that form. My two cents.